# Swift の enum型を for-inする方法

Tags: swift

```
enum Num: String{
    case Zero = "0", One = "1", Two = "2", Three = "3", Four = "4", Five = "5", Six = "6", Seven = "7", Eight = "8", Nine = "9", Ten = "10", Eleven = "11", Twelve = "12"
}
```

このようなenumがあった場合にfor inさせるにはどのような方法がありますか？

Answer (score 1, accepted):

少し違うかもしれませんが、英語版で似た質問を見つけました。
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24007461/how-to-enumerate-an-enum-with-string-type

// 英語版から転載

```
enum ProductCategory : String {
     case Washers = "washers", Dryers = "dryers", Toasters = "toasters"

     static let allValues = [Washers, Dryers, Toasters]
}

for category in ProductCategory.allValues{
     //Do something
}
```